# WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using oh-my-zsh and I get this error every time I open terminal:

```
WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh
```

is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Might seems silly, but make sure that you source your `~/.zshrc` file (create one if it does not exists). On OSX I completely forgot that I had switched to zsh, and got the error you mentioned because I was doing `source ~/.bashrc`

1. The easiest way to get auto-completion working is to install it through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (it will work for zsh as well as bash.):

```sh
brew install bash-completion
```

2. Put this into your `~/.zshrc`:

```
# auto-completion
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ]; then
  . /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
fi
```

3. Save the file and do a `source ~/.zshrc` and you will be good

Comment: This solved a 2-hour struggle for me after I switched to zsh. Thank you!

Comment: You saved me so much time. Thank you! I just switched to macOS and you're the only person who told me to create a `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Tks bro, i am new im Mac. Tks <3

Comment: @EzequielDeSimone I had to comment out "#source ~/git-completion.bash" in my zshrc to clear the warning even after following the instructions on this answer. Maybe that might help too.

Comment: The closest file I can find is `/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion`. But sourcing that in zsh gives lots of errors like `/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion:59: command not found: shopt`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381980/341466 resolve using this problem in my file is not added autoload -Uz compinit && compinit in zshrc

Comment: For this issue, my colleague just needed to remove references to bash_completion in the `.zshrc` file. We use ohmyzsh and autocompletion is already implemented.

Answer (score 7):

In Git for Windows, this message is emitted during execution of the file `etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh`, if the shell is not Bash.

`git-prompt.sh` sources `git-completion.bash` without looking at the shell name. That file checks that it is not run by Bash, emits that warning message and exits.

Here is the link to the respective code:
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L3509

You should look inside git-completion.zsh located in the same directory near this file and follow installation instructions provided in the comments in the beginning:

```
# The recommended way to install this script is to make a copy of it as a
# file named '_git' inside any directory in your fpath.
#
# For example, create a directory '~/.zsh/', copy this file to '~/.zsh/_git',
# and then add the following to your ~/.zshrc file:
#
#  fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)
```

Comment: could you clarify? is seems like the right solution in my case but i can't fully understand the instructions. could you provide more details or sources?
Seems relevant https://gist.github.com/fworks/af4c896c9de47d827d4caa6fd7154b6b?permalink_comment_id=4013716#gistcomment-4013716

Comment: In my case `echo "" > ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh` solved it

Answer (score 5):

For me, I simply had copied over the contents of `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.zprofile`when migrating to zsh. I simply removed this line which was the root cause of the warning message:

`source ~/.profile`

Comment: **source: no such file or directory: /Users/myuser/.profile**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Looks like ```~/.profile``` does not exist, so if you remove that line when copying over from ```~/.bash_profile``` to ```~/.zprofile``` you should not get that error

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem in git for windows. The reason is as stated by [wl2776](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69396005/21277295).

And for me, I solve this problem by replacing the `etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh` using the script in  https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

Answer (score -1):

Type this in your console:

`curl https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh -OL`

Add this in one of your `.profile` / `.bashrc` / `.zshrc`:

`source ~/git-completion.zsh`

Comment: I get the following errors from my zsh: zsh:12: command not found: ___main
(eval):1: no matches found: *:all-files
_tags:comptags:36: can only be called from completion function
_tags:comptry:55: can only be called from completion function
_tags:comptags:60: can only be called from completion function
_tags:comptags:67: can only be called from completion function

 zsh --version
zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) # I also use Oh My Zsh.

Comment: `_git:12: command not found: ___main
_git:15: command not found: _default
complete:13: command not found: compdef`

Comment: It says `git-completion.zsh:.:48: no such file or directory: 
_git:19: command not found: _default` at MacOS 11.