# zsh throw WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

I was trying to change zsh theme but messed it up. Now every time I open a new terminal it throws this warning for a sec before the warning disappear

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin && clear
>
> WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh

Following the trace of a similar Stackoverflow `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315201/warning-this-script-is-deprecated-please-see-git-completion-zsh`

I attempted what the answerer suggested by `brew install bash-completion`  However brew gives this error upon running brew cleanup `==>

```
`brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
```

While this does not affect normal usage most of the times, when attempting to `source ~/.bash_profile`
It will return this weird error

> WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh
> (base) [\033[0;35m]\u[\033[0;32m][\033[0;34m] \W $ [\033[0m]

And I've not found a solution yet. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you trying to source a **bash** script in **zsh**?

Comment: @santoku : And what is the point of installing a git-**completion** package for **bash**, if you are not using bash? As a starting point, I would look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh),